# Find minimum trips to link 500 bulbs to 500 switches

Tags: analytical

There are 500 bulbs in the hall of a palace. The switch control(with 500 switches) for these bulbs is located in another room. Unfortunately the switches are not marked with the bulb numbers. A new worker arrives. What is the minimum number of trips he has to make to the hall to know exactly which corresponds to which bulb?

Answer (score 1):

It is **498**.

First 497 trips will help him identify 497 links.

There are 3 bulbs remaining. He turns on one switch, wait for sometime and turns it off. Immediately he turns on the next switch.

Now he goes to the hall, one bulb will be ON, switch found. Two bulbs will be OFF, he feels those two bulbs, one will be hot as it was ON for sometime. Both switches found.